# stop Jquery validations for Cancel button

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using predifined cssclass to validate the form using jquery.

When I click on cancel button all validation in the form firing. How  can I stop those validation for cancel button?

Comment: because the cancel button is not a cancel button but a submit button?

Comment: SO, How many more times are you going to change the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asp.net  you can use UseSubmitBehavior="false" as

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a css class "cancel" to your button to suppress the validation

```
<input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

Official documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Skipping_validation_on_submit

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
```

Comment: Is this working for you or not? If you need to disable vallidation for ASP and this is not working. Check out my answer..

Comment: hi phani , I don't do asp.net. you could try this : `<asp:Button 
    runat="server" 
    ID="uxResetButton" 
    Text="Cancel" 
    OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;" 
    />` Otherwise keeping the `<input../>` in your `.aspx` file also serve your purpose.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;" CssClass="basicBtn"
OnClick="BtnCancel_Click" />

Comment: The event handler is not invoking because button is returning `false`. If you put `OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return true;"` then it will again submit the form (which was reset-ed). In that case, it will  surely call the event-handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
```